# Javascript RegEx: extract words and separators in sequential array

Tags: javascript, regex

How in JavaScript to parse string and extract only words, but leave int the resulting array the other text parts that separate words.

```
"  This is - a string.  With two  and one spaces!"
```

to:

```
['  ', 'This', ' - ', 'a', ' ', 'string', '.  ', 'With']
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write:

```
var resultArray = origString.split(/\b/);
```

Links:

- [MDN page on `String.split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)
- [MDN page on regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) (search the page for `\b` or "word boundary")